Is there a problem with using a long life JWT with a revocation date field attached to the user?
I'm working on a monolithic application that uses a SQLite database, so database reads are quite inexpensive. In my application, I frequently need to query user information anyway. I'm considering an approach where I use long-lived JWTs and skip refresh tokens entirely. Instead, I plan to have a cancel_date field (or similar) attached to each user in the database. This field would represent a timestamp, and any JWT issued before this timestamp would be considered invalid.  Also, of course could be nullable.
This approach would allow me to effectively revoke JWTs by updating the cancelDate field in the user's record, without having to manage refresh tokens.
Are there any potential security or performance issues with this approach that I'm overlooking? Is there a better or more commonly accepted pattern for managing token invalidation in a similar context?

Why don't you just use plain old sessions? JWTs are not meant for maintaining a user session, and your solution is not stateless anyway. https://gist.github.com/samsch/0d1f3d3b4745d778f78b230cf6061452

@GaborLengyel because DB writes in SQLite are expensive, and that would increase db size.  But how is this not just as stateless as revocable refresh tokens?

Revocable tokens are also not stateless, revocation status is the state itself. :) But this is just a play on words. JWTs are used way more often than they are actually a good solution. Obviously, I don't know about your usecase, they may be good for you, I just wanted to raise attention to a different pov. Also separate access and refresh tokens mostly only make sense if they are stored differently (eg. for different origins, or the refresh token in a httponly cookie for the idp). So I can actually think of low enough security requirements for an app that your solution is ok.

@GaborLengyel yeah, whether it is or isn't stateless doesn't really matter for my use case.

@GaborLengyel, there are many misunderstandings of JWTs and sessions in the link you shared. The alternative suggested is not mutually exclusive of JWTs. I think what was intended to be said was to use a session token that maps to a JWT. A session token should be meaningless to anyone other than the authz server which has the JWT and the mapping of session tokens to JWTs. While, in general this is more secure and the simplest way to make it so, it's not possible for all application architectures and JWTs simply aren't defined as this person lays out.

TLDR;
Your question bounces around a few different things, so please clarify in a comment, and I will update accordingly, but I think most importantly from what you've said so far:
Mapping a token revocation status in the backend is commonplace for controlling/checking the revoked status of a token, but that's not the intended purpose of refresh tokens.
So, a backend revocation attribute is not a direct substitute for using refresh tokens.

Your question kind of hits on different topics. If it's a consideration of performance, having to hit the DB is still more costly than validating info contained within the JWT itself. But, it's commonly added to increase security because of the additional protection of checking data stored separately from the JWT and the ease of updating a DB vs. making sure old, expired JWTs aren't out in the wild.
You'll want to be cautious using a date vs. a boolean flag or similar as it can be easy for mistakes or mishandlings to creep up because you're replying on a correct interpretation of the date as opposed to a boolean directly stated whether a token is valid or not, no wiggle room for misinterpretation.
But, it doesn't replace the security that refresh tokens provide.
Ideally, refresh tokens should have the same mechanism in place, i.e., an attribute mapped to the user denoting whether a refresh token has been revoked/is valid.

However, it depends on your situation. What kinds of JWTs are these? Access tokens, ID tokens, or it could be a number of other things.
Often, the biggest risk is with access tokens as they allow for more than just seeing info, like an ID token would reveal info about the user (but, you're not storing sensitive info in an ID token without encrypting it, right?).
The OAuth 2 and JWT(/JWS/JWE) standards allow for JWTs to be verified on their own. If the signature is verified, and whatever checks passed using info within the JWT itself (e.g., if the expiration date has passed, it's intended for the right audience, and so on), the access token is considered valid.
This is often considered a downside, but it's resolved by adding additional protections like a separately stored revocation list. But, that doesn't replace the other protections from short-lived JWTs.
You impose stricter regulations, like
requiring hitting the authz server in addition to the checks listed above
(which would check your revocation attribute in the DB) and make sure there isn't a route outside of that.

If you can ensure the only server using the tokens are your backend and it must check the revocation list, you can do it without much risk, but it's a special case of using OAuth and JWTs, so you risk veering away from the standard where you're now designing your own security system instead of sticking with the standard that's been around and used for quite a while.

For further explanation,
Imagine a scale from least secure to most secure as a generic illustration of best security practices.
"least" and "most" are at the extremes
least secure   <---------------->  most secure


Least secure:

a token that doesn't expire


Most secure:

a token with immediate expiration (e.g., one time use only)



non-expiring   <---------------->  one-time use
least secure                       most secure

But, this also tends to correlate with friction added to the user experience.

one-time use = most friction

user has to constantly re-authenticate


non-expiring = least friction

user has to only authenticate once at the beginning



least friction                     most friction
non-expiring   <---------------->  one-time use
least secure                       most secure

Refresh tokens were introduced as a middle ground, i.e., less friction than one-time use but more secure than a non-expiring token.
The user doesn't have to re-authenticate if there's a valid refresh token. But, the refresh token doesn't itself allow access to anything. The process to exchange it for an (access) token provides the opportunity to put some protections in place.
                    
least friction       refresh       most friction
non-expiring   <---------------->  one-time use
least secure         tokens        most secure


The only thing the token contains is an internal essentially random user id.  Because of this encrypting is pointless, and it will just be signed.  Since that means user data has to be looked up anyways, I don't view including cancel_date as a big cost.  I'm not wanting to use session tokens because writing is much more expensive than reading in SQLite

A random id used to lookup user data is a session token.
https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet.html#:~:text=In%20order%20to%20keep,on%20every%20HTTP%20request).

the difference(from my understanding) is that the random ID I'm passing isn't added to a session table, instead its generated on user creation, in my case I'm just using the user row ID.

Are you using the same ID after the user is logged out (by expiring via cancelDate) and then they log in again?
The immediate difference I see is you're mapping that ID directly to the user data vs. a session token mapped to some kind of session data or authentication token. Directly to the user is less secure and you don't have any info about their authenticated state.

Why is it less secure if the signature is verified?  And other then being authorized/unauthorized and getting user data from the DB there is no state to store(other than the user ID itself), since all the state could easily be invalidated by a modification on another device, so a DB lookup would be needed anyways.

Verifying a signature only tells you whether the signed thing has been tampered with. That's fine and not what I'm talking about. I'm referring to the fact that you can add a layer of obfuscation between your DB and the client by not using the same ID in the token as the user row ID.

"can add a layer of obfuscation between your DB and the client by not using the same ID in the token as the user row ID" yes you could, but what would the point of that be?

What's the point of obfuscation in security? Ultimately, implementing security involves deciding what amount of risk you're comfortable taking. I'm just providing potential ways to increase security, in case you wanted to use it. If you don't think it outweighs the effort or performance costs or it's not relevant for your use case, then it's okay to pass on it.

I just don't see how that would improve security

The potential security issue is that if someone manages to steal a token somehow, they have very long-lasting access as that user. Will you have a good way to track that down? If not, what should have been a temporary theft becomes a permanent one. This escalates the impact of a risk.
The potential performance issue is that you're now relying on sticking more and more information in the JWT. The JWT has to be sent back and forth on every network request. This is expensive in bandwidth and potential latency.
The potential future bug problem is what happens when you want to change something in the structure of the JWT. It is hard to properly test what happens when an old JWT goes through new code, and so that becomes an easy way to introduce bugs that are likely to be missed in QA. (Yes, yes, just update everyone's cancel_date. But that another step that some day you'll forget to do.)
The antipattern that I see is continuing to use SQLite for web development in a situation where you already are aware of the negative performance implications. SQLite is a brilliant piece of software that is absolutely the best choice in a wide variety of use cases. But it's not a general-purpose replacement for PostgreSQL. Eventually you'll need to replace it with a database that is better at concurrency. The longer you put that decision off, the more painful it would be. I would therefore strongly advise switching to a more suitable database engine, and not trying weird workarounds for the limitations of SQLite.

No, you're misunderstanding, SQLite is extremely performant(10 SQLite reads perform far better than 1 detached read), and extremely valuable for this application(generally low traffic, limited resources).  And, the JWT is not having significantly more information added.  I explain how stolen JWTs would be handled, that is by invalidating JWTs issued before cancel_date.  The JWT also does not need to store any data other than the user id because of the performance of SQLite for reads, but if it were, that's trivial to solve with a version field.

No, I don't misunderstand. You're designing your software around concurrent write performance limitations. That's a code smell that won't get better. And yes, you explained your strategy for stolen JWTs. That's great for the attacks that you know about. But timeouts and refresh tokens create an inconvenience for the attacks that you don't know about. That's why they were invented in the first place.

How would refresh tokens be any different?  If the attacker has access to the refresh token(no less likely than if they had access to the JWT) "inconcenience" isn't security.
As for concurrent write limitations, I recommend you look at WAL performance as compared to detached SQL servers.  When I say performance limitations, I never said anything anywhere near as bad as a detached SQL server. Ie, even with synchronous FULL in SQLite performance might only be 10x faster than Postgres for writes, but 100x faster reads is by far worth it. I suggest you read more on SQLite and test it yourself

@Aidan As far as I can tell, you have come up with an idea that you think is good, and don't want to hear contrary opinions from more experienced people. So I'll stop after this comment. A standard web configuration with failover has a lot of requirements around parallel access by multiple processes on multiple machines. The question isn't throughput, it is lock contention. As for why refresh tokens are different, you can add lots of expensive sanity checks to a rare refresh. Like don't refresh twice in time X, and does this look like the right machine?

I do want to hear genuine security concerns, but unfounded misconceptions about the performance of SQLite aren't really relevant.  Yes, SQLite file locks prohibit simultaneous write, the question is for a non-extremely high use application, will the delay of a write queue ever exceed the back and forth delay from a detached server.  For a read heavy application it's almost certain the answer is no.  You're right though that n reads is cheaper than n + 1 reads no matter how cheap a single read is.  I'm just concerned if there is a significant security risk if for the sake of dev time,

refresh tokens aren't immediately included.  And instead that read(which again needs to be done anyways) for "cancellation" is done.  So, given the scenario where a read on every login is needed anyways, even if using a detached SQL server(with much slower reads), in that case, how are refresh tokens any more performant than a cancellation date?  "you can add lots of expensive sanity checks to a rare refresh." this is a good answer and something I hadn't considered for example.  But the question is "lot of requirements around parallel access" are these requirements always justified, cost wise
